# How to get a querystring when it is URLEncoded or has percent characters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, query-string, urlencode

How to get the actual querystring from the Request object when the querystring is  UrlEncoded or has percent characters in ASP.NET?

Basicly, if I have a Url like this: `Default.aspx?p=%b4`, how do I get a string populated with "%b4"?

`Request.QueryString["p"]` returns a non printable character.

`Request.RawUrl` returns Default.aspx?p=%ufffd"

`Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` returns Default.aspx?p=%EF%BF%BD

How can I get "%b4" back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug into this further, and believe I know what's causing this: an HTTP client is submitting a URL to the server which is not properly URL-encoded. Specifically, there is an invalid character in the URL.

To repro, paste the following at the end of your URL into IE8: `default.aspx?p=´`

If you examine the bytes going over the wire (e.g. using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)), you'll see an actual Hex B4 character is being sent from client to server in the URL.  This is an illegal character in a URL, since URLs are limited to char codes under 0x80 (any larger-than-0x80 char codes must be percent-escaped).

So your client is passing in an invalid character, and your server is (correctly) replacing the bogus character with %EF%BF%BD which is the UTF-8 encoding for the [Unicode Replacement Character (U+0FFD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), which is what happens when a character is encountered which has no equivalent in the local encoding.

AFAIK, this is a bug in IE.  If you type the same URL into Firefox, Firefox will encode the URL properly (as %b4 instead of ´).  Note that, also AFAIK, the problem only happens when manually pasting invalid characters into IE's address bar-- if the same character is present in a link, IE seems to encode the URL properly (at least in the cases I tested).

So you should figure out who is sending this bogus URL to you, and tell them to start encoding their URLs properly!

Comment: Hmm. I tested the code above on IE8 and asp.net 3.5.  I wonder if this is a browser-specific thing where the browser is doing the encoding before your code gets ahold of it?  Or perhaps a .net version's behavior difference? What browser and .net version are you using? Also, what is the Request Encoding of your page? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx for more info about encoding.

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks, I will research further.

Comment: BTW, I dug into this a little more and came up with what I think is the cause of the problem you're seeing. take a look at my revised answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net will automatically URL Decode stuff when you do Request.Querystring["key"].  You just need to encode it again.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["p"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]
```

will return the RAW Query String

Comment: No, this returns an unprintable character.

Comment: try
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it just by adding in javascript "escape('text % text')" while contructing the querystring!