# JQuery autocomplete for unicode character

Tags: asp.net, unicode, urlencode, jquery-autocomplete

Is there any JQuery autocomplete for Unicode character(Thai).
I already with [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) and that my code for asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var q = Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["q"]);
    Response.Write(q);
}
```

The URL is http://localhost:2286/customerauto.aspx?q=%E0%B8%93 like that.

I got `q="%e0%b8%93";` actually the correct value is    **ณ** .
So I don't know client side encoding is wrong or server side encoding is wrong ?

Pls Help me

Comment: No, the correct URL value is actually `q="%e0%b8%93";`, because ณ needs to be [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: @Matt Ball So How to change to ณ from "%e0%b8%93" ?

Comment: Are you testing with Internet Explorer? If so, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638499/how-to-get-a-querystring-when-it-is-urlencoded-or-has-percent-characters-in-asp-n)

Comment: ...otherwise, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405048/how-to-decode-url-param-with-c).

Answer (score 0):

when u want to transfer UTF8 string just

```
Response.Write("this string represent UTF8");
```

and set page encoding to UTF8