# Problems with UTF-8 character encoding from URL query string value in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8, query-string

I'm finding an odd issue in Internet Explorer, specifically IE9, when trying to display special characters (German accented characters) provided within the URL query string. **This is working as expected in Firefox and Chrome.**

For example, the URL I'm working with looks something like this:

```
http://mysite.com/TestPage.aspx?Title=Hochauflösendes®
```

I've also tried the URL encoded version of the URL:

```
http://mysite.com/TestPage.aspx?Title=Hochaufl%C3%B6sendes%C2%AE
```

In either case, when I'm trying to display that 'Title' query string value on my page using `Request.QueryString["Title"]`, IE doesn't display the characters correctly:

```
Hochaufl�sendes�
```

**If I hard-code the text directly on the page, it displays properly on all browsers.** It's only when it's pulling from the query string where the issue occurs.

The page is saved as UTF-8 encoding, and I have the `meta` tag in my page as necessary:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

I've also looked at the page's header and content via Fiddler, and all the encoding is correct.

What could be causing IE not to display the special characters properly?

Comment: I do not remember why, but I have the same issue and solve it by manually extract the parameters from the `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`. By manually, I mean that I have made a custom function that gets the RawUrl and extract the parametres and not use the QueryString.

Comment: @Aristos That's a good idea worth trying. I did find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638499/how-to-get-a-querystring-when-it-is-urlencoded-or-has-percent-characters-in-asp), which explores the different ways of getting the value, but also suggests this could be a bug in IE, though this was from 2009.

Comment: @Aristos Using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` worked. I then retrieved the value using the method found in [this post](http://dot-net-web-developer-bristol.blogspot.com/2010/08/getting-parameters-from-rawurl.html).

Comment: Then I suggest you to make it an answer and describe how you solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Aristos, using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` worked for my situation.

To retrieve the actual query string value from the RawUrl, a simple method like this can be used:

```
private string GetQueryStringValueFromRawUrl(string queryStringKey)
{
    var currentUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + 
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + 
        HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    var queryStringCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString((currentUri).Query);
    return queryStringCollection.Get(queryStringKey);
}
```

Retrieving the value using this method was tested as working in IE8 and IE9. The bug is fixed in IE10.

Comment: I'm tried just now. input value "iiiĞĞĞiiiŞŞŞ" output value "iiiÞÞÞÞÞðððÐÐÐÐ" browser last ie version.